# Position Manager return TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE in HERE MAPS

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to get the state of position manager in onEngineInitializationCompleted But  i am getting TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE all the time .How to fix this ?

I have checked the state of position manager it is showing me active .

```
            switch (error) {
                case NONE:
                    map = new Map();
                    mapView.setMap(map);
                    mPositionManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                    map.setMapScheme(map.getMapSchemes().get(2));
                    map.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
                    mPositionManager.addListener(new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(CreateBoundaryAlertFragment.this));

                    if (mPositionManager != null) {
                        Log.e("mPositionManager", mPositionManager.getLocationStatus(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK).toString());
                        if (mPositionManager.getLocationStatus(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK) == PositioningManager.LocationStatus.AVAILABLE) {
                            map.setZoomLevel(17, Map.Animation.LINEAR);
                        } else if (mPositionManager.getLocationStatus(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK) == PositioningManager.LocationStatus.OUT_OF_SERVICE ||
                                mPositionManager.getLocationStatus(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK) == PositioningManager.LocationStatus.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE) {
                            updateCamera(Constants.HereMapInitial.INDIA_CENTER, Constants.HereMapInitial.COUNTRY_INDIA_ZOOM_LEVEL);                   
                        }
                    }
                 mapView.setCopyrightLogoPosition(CopyrightLogoPosition.TOP_LEFT);
                    mStateOfMapEngine = true;
                    break;
                case BUSY:
                    mStateOfMapEngine = false;
                    break;
                case UNKNOWN:
                    mStateOfMapEngine = false;
                    break;
                case MISSING_PERMISSION:
                    break;
            }
```

I have added the start method in onCreate method and then called the mapInt method in which switch case is present.

```
 if (mPositionManager != null) {
        mPositionManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
    }
```

Comment: Why thumbs down ? I am facing this issue ,help me out!!

Comment: Did you check what _start_ method returned? Maybe you forgot to enable _ACCESS_LOCATION_ permissions.

Comment: @NazarK I have given Location permission. The Here maps return GeoCode's. Which start Method? Is it because i have added the code in    ` OnEngineInitListener engineInitHandler = new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {}  `?

Comment: Method _PositionManager.start()_ returns _boolean_

Comment: First of all you have to init _MapEngine_ before you call any method of the SDK. Only then you can use any functionality. So if you call _PositionManager.start()_ before _onEngineInitializationCompleted_ then this is wrong, it has to be used after _engine_ has been successfully initialized.

Comment: I noticed one thing the PositionManager takes some 5 -10 seconds to get the data .Because of this i was not able to get the result immediately .Thank you @NazarK

Answer (score 0):

That error can happen when you try to init map from background. If you need more details, in void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error), try error.getDetails() and error.getStackTrace()

**Method Detail**

> onEngineInitializationCompleted void
>   onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error)

A
callback indicating that map engine initialization has completed. Parameters: error - If map engine initialized successfully, returns OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE. Otherwise, one of the other OnEngineInitListener.Error enum values indicating the reason of factory initialization failure.